# Multiple collection of terms

Tags: factorization

As the title suggests, I am interested in how to perform multiple collection of terms. This means that for a given expression `a*x*b + c*x^2*d+a*x*k`, I want to  collect first in powers of `x` and for each factor of of a power of x to collect again in terms of another variable. In the previous example this translates to 
`(a(b+k))*x+c*d*x^2`. Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't `Collect[expr, {x, a}]` do what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved it:

`myexpression//Collect[#,{myoutermostparameters},Collect[#,{myinnermostparameters}]&]&`

This gives the proper nested factorisation for any parameters needed.